# Professional ways of tracking GPU memory leakage (allocation without deallocation)

Tags: c#, c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm looking for an advice of how to track GPU memory leakage origins inside the source code.

I have a large, multi-threaded, c# / c++ application which suffers from small, but deterministic, memory leakage issues when some specific actions are repeated. I also have memory scanner running next to this application, so I can track memory usage statistics in real time. Because I know which actions are responsible for memory usage growth, I'm able to outline the code frames where these bad things happens. Next, I put breakpoints within these frames, attach debugger, and step by step check for the memory usage peaks. I want to track areas where the memory is allocated, but never released, thus causing the leakage.

My way of investigation is really poor (and the same time hard due to the code complexity and multiple threads playing around). Are there any professional ways of tracking and solving such an issues?

Answer (score 2):

I use a small selection of tools, however I find the following to offer the most concise set of tools for my needs, perhaps they will suit yours:

- CodeXL from AMD: http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/
- Nvidia NSight: https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworks-tools-overview
- Nvidia Visual Profiler: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler
- gDebugger: http://www.gremedy.com/

Depending on what I am doing and what I need to track/trace and profile I utilise all 4 packages above.  They also have the added benefit of being a: free; b: well maintained; c: free; d: regularly updated; e: free.

In case you hadn't guessed I like the free part:)

In regards of object management, I would recommend an old C++ coding principle: as soon as you create an object, add the line that deletes it, every new should always (eventually) have a delete.  That way you know that you are destroying the objects you create, however it will not save you from *orphaned memory block* memory leaks, where you change where pointers are pointing, for example:

```
myclass* firstInstance = new myclass();
myclass* secondInstance = new myclass();
firstInstance = secondInstance;
delete firstInstance;
delete secondInstance;
```

You will now have created a small memory leak where the data for the real firstInstance is now not being pointed at by any pointer.  Very hard to detect when this happens in a large code-base, and more common that it should be.

generally these are the pairings you need to be aware of to ensure you properly dispose of all your objects:

```
new -> delete
new[] -> delete[]
malloc() -> free() // or you can use realloc(0) instead of free()
calloc() -> free() // or you can use realloc(0) instead of free()
realloc(nonzero) -> free() // or you can use realloc(0) instead of free()
```

If you are coming from a language with garbage collection to C++ it can take a while to get used to, but it quickly becomes habit:)